# unresolved external symbol referenced in function removed by /OPT:REF

Tags: visual-c++

I have a function bar() that I don't actually call, that calls unimplemented foo():

```
void foo();
void bar()
{
    foo();
}
int main()
{

}
```

If I package each function in a separate section/COMDAT and ask the linker to remove unused sections/COMDAT, I can get gcc to compile the program

```
gcc -ffunction-sections -Xlinker --gc-sections LinkerFunctions.cpp
```

but the equivalent in Visual C++ 2019

```
cl /Gy LinkerFunctions.cpp /link /OPT:REF
```

barks that

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl foo(void)" (?foo@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl bar(void)" (?bar@@YAXXZ)
```

How can I get msvc to compile the program?

Comment: what version of the compiler are you using?

Comment: @DanielA.White Visual Studio 2019. Just updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: Might be the same issue: [\[SO\]: Why are dependencies different between these two MSVC C++ project configurations (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75785719/4788546).

Answer (score 5):

Got your example working by adding `inline`, even after adding `__declspec(noinline)` to prevent actual inlining.

```
void foo();

__declspec(noinline)
inline void bar()
{
    foo();
}

int main()
{

}
```

Tried because the documentation says:

> Inlined functions and member functions defined inside a class declaration are always COMDATs.

Not sure however if it is robust solution, or works just in this particular case.

Comment: `static void bar() { ... }` appears to work, too. It looks like otherwise VS has a problem realizing that `bar` is not referenced from elsewhere, even with "*whole program optimizations*" turned on.

Answer (score 2):

Accidentally found a linker switch for that:

```
cl incomplete.cpp /link /FORCE:UNRESOLVED
```

Will give a warning but in fact will work.