# Why are dependencies different between these two MSVC C++ project configurations

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

I am writing a C++ DLL (Plugin.dll) which depends on a static library (lib_a.lib).

I also maintain lib_a, which has a source file Stuff.cpp. In stuff.cpp two functions are implemented:

```
#include <third_party_library/MyHeader.h>
...

//This function depends on third_party_library
bool Stuff::Foo(MyType* arg1)
{
    bool success = ThirdPartyLib::Bar(arg1); //Declared in third_party_library/MyHeader.h
    if (!success) { return false; }
}

//This function does not depend on third_party_library
bool Stuff::Foo(MyType* arg1, MyType2* arg2)
{
    bool success = Stuff::SomeOtherFunc(arg1, arg2);
    if (!success) { return false; }
}

...
```

In Plugin.dll, there is a call to the second function, which does *not* depend on third_party_library. There are no calls to the first function in Plugin.dll (and I have traced every possible call stack to verify that there can be no downstream calls to the first function). Therefore, Plugin functions do not actually call anything depending on third_party_library (none of Plugin's other dependencies depend on third_party_library; the only way for this dependency to occur would be through lib_a as described).

When I build Plugin in the release configuration, then check dependencies in the Visual Studio terminal window using the command `dumpbin /DEPENDENTS C:\path\to\build\x64\Release\Plugin.dll`, third_party_library.dll is not listed as a dependency. However, when I build Plugin in the debug configuration and check the dependencies of Plugind.dll, third_party_libraryd.dll (the debug version of third_party_library) *is* listed as a dependency. **I know that this dependency comes from Plugin's call to `Stuff:Foo(MyType* arg1)` because the dependency is eliminated if I comment out this call and rebuild.**

I assumed this discrepancy was due to linker optimizations (/OPT:REF) being enabled for the release configuration and not the debug configuration, but enabling linker optimizations in the debug configuration did not solve the problem.

In fact, I even started from scratch and made a new debug configuration that was an exact copy of my release configuration except for the following:

1. Debug has the preprocessor definition _DEBUG, Release has NDEBUG
2. In 'Linker options->Additional Dependencies,' the Debug configuration lists the debug version of each library while the Release configuration lists the release version of each library
3. Debugger information is generated in the Debug build (/Debug/Zi)

(This configuration is not so useful for actual debugging, I just made it to get to the bottom of the problem).

Yet I still get a dependency on third_party_libraryd.dll in my debug build. I would really like to eliminate this unused dependency so I don't have to keep this dll in my repo (I have this same problem with several third party libraries, so they are sizable all put together) or distribute it on the occasion I have to deploy a debug build internally.

So my question is, **why might Plugind.dll still depend on third_party_libraryd.dll and is there a way for me to eliminate this dependency?**

The compiler command line options in the Debug configuration are:

/JMC /GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /I"C:\our\include\paths" /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"x64\Debug\vc141.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_DEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "CV4" /D "G3D9" /D "_USRDLL" /D "SIMPLENATIVELIBRARY_EXPORTS" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /D "_AFXDLL" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi /MDd /FC /Fa"x64\Debug" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Debug" /Fp"x64\Debug\Plugind.pch" /diagnostics:classic

The compiler command line options in the Release configuration are:

/JMC /GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /I"C:\our\include\paths" /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"x64\Release\vc141.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "NDEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "CV4" /D "G3D9" /D "_USRDLL" /D "SIMPLENATIVELIBRARY_EXPORTS" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /D "_AFXDLL" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi /MD /FC /Fa"x64\Release" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release" /Fp"x64\Release\Plugin.pch" /diagnostics:classic

The linker command line options in the Debug configuration are:

/OUT:"C:\path\to\build\x64\Debug\Plugind.dll" /MANIFEST /LTCG:incremental /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\path\to\build\x64\Debug\Plugind.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "lib_a_debug.lib" "third_party_libraryd.lib" "other_dependencies_debug.lib" /IMPLIB:"C:\path\to\build\x64\Debug\Plugind.lib" /DEBUG /DLL /MACHINE:X64 /NODEFAULTLIB:"LIBCMT" /OPT:REF /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"C:\path\to\build\x64\Debug\Plugind.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"x64\Debug\Plugind.dll.intermediate.manifest" /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\our\library_paths" /TLBID:1

The linker command line options in the Release configuration are:

/OUT:"C:\path\to\build\x64\Release\Plugin.dll" /MANIFEST /LTCG:incremental /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\path\to\build\x64\Release\Plugin.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "lib_a.lib" "third_party_library.lib" "other_dependencies.lib" /IMPLIB:"C:\path\to\build\x64\Release\Plugin.lib" /DEBUG /DLL /MACHINE:X64 /NODEFAULTLIB:"LIBCMT" /OPT:REF /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"C:\path\to\build\x64\Release\Plugin.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"x64\Release\Plugin.dll.intermediate.manifest" /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\our\library_paths" /TLBID:1

Comment: That seems to say `third_party_libraryd.lib` was an import library and not a static library.

Comment: @drescherjm correct, third_party_libraryd.lib is in an import library for third_party_libraryd.dll. I don't think I ever said it was a static library? To be clear, lib_a.lib is a static library, which I maintain, that contains some functions that need third_party_library.dll

Comment: Perhaps the most direct thing is to split your lib into two -- one with the dependency and one without.

Comment: Or rather, use `#ifdef USE_THIRDPARTY_THING`

Comment: which implies building the lib two different ways, hence creating two libraries.

Answer (score 2):

As you already mentioned, the culprit for your dependency difference (in *Debug* / *Release* modes) is [[MS.Learn]: /OPT (Optimizations)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/opt-optimizations) (different settings for the 2 configurations) which states (*emphasis* is mine):

> *By default, **/OPT:REF** is enabled by the linker unless **/OPT:NOREF** or [/DEBUG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/debug-generate-debug-info) is specified*. To override this default and keep unreferenced COMDATs in the program, specify **/OPT:NOREF**. You can use the [/INCLUDE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/include-force-symbol-references) option to override the removal of a specific symbol.
>
> *If [/DEBUG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/debug-generate-debug-info) is specified, the default for **/OPT** is **NOREF**, and all functions are preserved in the image*. To override this default and optimize a debug build, specify **/OPT:REF**.

That was **the *WHY* part**.

You mentioned that adding */OPT:REF* did not solve the problem, so I created an *MCVE* ([[SO]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) and it worked on my side (simply setting *References* option to */OPT:REF* and rebuilding, the *Plugin.dll* equivalent **didn't depend** on the 3<sup>rd</sup>-party one).
As it's impossible to demo it from *VStudio* (*GUI* - maybe record a video and post it somewhere?), I'm posting the *CmdLine* (*NMake* - check the 2<sup>nd</sup> *URL* in list at the end) variant.

**Note**: **When building (*NMake*), I hit the same problem you did**. After hours of investigations (went through a couple of options (*e.g.*: */Zc:inline*), I found **the culprit**: [[MS.Learn]: /Gy (Enable Function-Level Linking)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gy-enable-function-level-linking) - which was automatically enabled (by */ZI* - which was set) in *VStudio*, but **not** (by */Zi*) in *NMake*)

- *include/common.h*:

  ```cpp
  #pragma once

  #include <iostream>

  #define DBG_MSG0() std::cout << "[" << __FILE__ << "] " << __LINE__ << " (" << __FUNCTION__ << ")\n"
  ```
- *include/dll00.h*:

  ```cpp
  #pragma once

  #if defined(_WIN32)
  #  if defined(DLL00_STATIC)
  #    define DLL00_EXPORT_API
  #  else
  #    if defined(DLL00_EXPORTS)
  #      define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
  #    else
  #      define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllimport)
  #    endif
  #  endif
  #else
  #  define DLL00_EXPORT_API
  #endif


  class DLL00_EXPORT_API Dll00Cls00 {
  public:
      static void meth00();
  };
  ```
- *dll00/src/dll00.cpp*:

  ```cpp
  #include <dll00.h>
  #include "common.h"


  void Dll00Cls00::meth00()
  {
      DBG_MSG0();
  }
  ```
- *include/lib00.h*:

  ```cpp
  #pragma once

  #if defined(_WIN32)
  #  if defined(LIB00_STATIC)
  #    define LIB00_EXPORT_API
  #  else
  #    if defined(LIB00_EXPORTS)
  #      define LIB00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
  #    else
  #      define LIB00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllimport)
  #    endif
  #  endif
  #else
  #  define LIB00_EXPORT_API
  #endif


  class LIB00_EXPORT_API Lib00Cls00 {
  public:
      static void meth00();
      static void meth01_use_dll00();
  };
  ```
- *lib00/src/lib00.cpp*:

  ```cpp
  #include <lib00.h>
  #include "common.h"
  #include <dll00.h>


  void Lib00Cls00::meth00()
  {
      DBG_MSG0();
  }

  void Lib00Cls00::meth01_use_dll00()
  {
      Dll00Cls00::meth00();
      DBG_MSG0();
  }
  ```
- *include/dll01.h*:

  ```cpp
  #pragma once

  #if defined(_WIN32)
  #  if defined(DLL01_STATIC)
  #    define DLL01_EXPORT_API
  #  else
  #    if defined(DLL01_EXPORTS)
  #      define DLL01_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
  #    else
  #      define DLL01_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllimport)
  #    endif
  #  endif
  #else
  #  define DLL01_EXPORT_API
  #endif


  class DLL01_EXPORT_API Dll01Cls00 {
  public:
      static void meth00();
  };
  ```
- *dll01/src/dll01.cpp*:

  ```cpp
  #include <dll01.h>
  #include "common.h"
  #include <lib00.h>


  void Dll01Cls00::meth00()
  {
      Lib00Cls00::meth00();
      //Lib00Cls00::meth01_use_dll00();
      DBG_MSG0();
  }
  ```
- *app00/src/app00.cpp*:

  ```cpp
  #include <dll01.h>
  #include "common.h"


  int main()
  {
      Dll01Cls00::meth00();
      DBG_MSG0();

      return 0;
  }
  ```
- *Makefile.mak* (note that I just created it to quickly build 4 source files - **it's not robust at all** in terms of dependencies and should not be used in production, also I only ran it (and customized it) for debug builds):

  ```nmake
  !include <NtWin32.mak>

  RM=del /f /q

  DLL00=dll00
  LIB00=lib00
  DLL01=dll01
  APP00=app00

  FLAGS_COMPILER=/EHsc /Iinclude /D_DEBUG /Gy
  FLAGS_LINKER=/INCREMENTAL
  !if ("$(OPTREF)" == "")
  OUTD=bin/regular
  !else
  OUTD=bin/optref
  FLAGS_LINKER=$(FLAGS_LINKER) /OPT:REF
  !endif
  FLAGS_LINKER=$(FLAGS_LINKER) /LIBPATH:$(OUTD)

  cflags=$(cflags:-c =)
  #cdebug=$(cdebug:-Zi=/ZI)  # Sets /Gy implicitly

  all: $(OUTD)/$(APP00).exe

  clean:
      -$(RM) "$(OUTD)"\*
      -$(RM) *.lib *.exp *.pdb *.obj *.idb

  $(OUTD)/$(APP00).exe: $(APP00)/src/$(APP00).cpp $(OUTD)/$(DLL01).dll
      -@echo --- Building $@ ---
      $(CXX) /nologo $(cdebug) $(cflags) $(cvarsdll) $(FLAGS_COMPILER) $(APP00)/src/$(APP00).cpp  /link /NOLOGO $(ldebug) $(FLAGS_LINKER) $(DLL01).lib $(conlflags) $(conlibsdll) /OUT:$@

  $(OUTD)/$(DLL01).dll: $(DLL01)/src/$(DLL01).cpp $(OUTD)/$(LIB00).lib
      -@echo --- Building $@ ---
      $(CXX) /nologo $(cdebug) $(cflags) $(cvarsdll) $(FLAGS_COMPILER) /DDLL01_EXPORTS /DLIB00_STATIC $(DLL01)/src/$(DLL01).cpp  /link /NOLOGO $(ldebug) $(FLAGS_LINKER) $(dlllflags) $(LIB00).lib $(conlibsdll) /OUT:$@

  $(OUTD)/$(LIB00).lib: $(LIB00)/src/$(LIB00).cpp $(OUTD)/$(DLL00).dll
      -@echo --- Building $@ ---
      $(CXX) /nologo $(cdebug) $(cflags) $(cvarsdll) $(FLAGS_COMPILER) /DLIB00_STATIC /c $(LIB00)/src/$(LIB00).cpp
      lib /NOLOGO $(ldebug) $(FLAGS_LINKER) $(LIB00).obj $(DLL00).lib /OUT:$@

  $(OUTD)/$(DLL00).dll: $(DLL00)/src/$(DLL00).cpp
      -@echo --- Building $@ ---
      $(CXX) /nologo $(cdebug) $(cflags) $(cvarsdll) $(FLAGS_COMPILER) /DDLL00_EXPORTS $?  /link /NOLOGO $(ldebug) $(FLAGS_LINKER) $(dlllflags) $(conlibsdll) /OUT:$@
  ```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q075759550]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 > nul
>
> [prompt]> set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;e:\Work\Dev\GitHub\CristiFati\MSSDKFiles\src\Include
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dir /b bin\regular bin\optref
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: Build "regularly"
> [prompt]> nmake /nologo /f Makefile.mak OPTREF= clean all
>         del /f /q "bin/regular"\*
>         del /f /q *.lib *.exp *.pdb *.obj *.idb
> Could Not Find e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q075759550\*.lib*
> --- Building bin/regular/dll00.dll ---
>         cl /nologo -Zi -Od -DDEBUG -DCRTAPI1=_cdecl -DCRTAPI2=_cdecl -nologo -GS -D_AMD64_=1 -DWIN64 -D_WIN64  -DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -W4 -D_WINNT -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DNTDDI_VERSION=0x06000000 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0700 -DWINVER=0x0600  -D_MT -D_DLL -MDd /EHsc /Iinclude /D_DEBUG /Gy /DDLL00_EXPORTS dll00/src/dll00.cpp  /link /NOLOGO /DEBUG /DEBUGTYPE:cv /INCREMENTAL /LIBPATH:bin/regular  /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO -entry:_DllMainCRTStartup -dll kernel32.lib  ws2_32.lib mswsock.lib advapi32.lib /OUT:bin/regular/dll00.dll
> dll00.cpp
>    Creating library bin\regular\dll00.lib and object bin\regular\dll00.exp
> --- Building bin/regular/lib00.lib ---
>         cl /nologo -Zi -Od -DDEBUG -DCRTAPI1=_cdecl -DCRTAPI2=_cdecl -nologo -GS -D_AMD64_=1 -DWIN64 -D_WIN64  -DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -W4 -D_WINNT -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DNTDDI_VERSION=0x06000000 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0700 -DWINVER=0x0600  -D_MT -D_DLL -MDd /EHsc /Iinclude /D_DEBUG /Gy /DLIB00_STATIC /c lib00/src/lib00.cpp
> lib00.cpp
>         lib /NOLOGO /DEBUG /DEBUGTYPE:cv /INCREMENTAL /LIBPATH:bin/regular lib00.obj dll00.lib /OUT:bin/regular/lib00.lib
> LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/DEBUG'; ignored
> LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/DEBUGTYPE:cv'; ignored
> LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/INCREMENTAL'; ignored
> --- Building bin/regular/dll01.dll ---
>         cl /nologo -Zi -Od -DDEBUG -DCRTAPI1=_cdecl -DCRTAPI2=_cdecl -nologo -GS -D_AMD64_=1 -DWIN64 -D_WIN64  -DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -W4 -D_WINNT -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DNTDDI_VERSION=0x06000000 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0700 -DWINVER=0x0600  -D_MT -D_DLL -MDd /EHsc /Iinclude /D_DEBUG /Gy /DDLL01_EXPORTS /DLIB00_STATIC dll01/src/dll01.cpp  /link /NOLOGO /DEBUG /DEBUGTYPE:cv /INCREMENTAL /LIBPATH:bin/regular  /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO -entry:_DllMainCRTStartup -dll lib00.lib kernel32.lib  ws2_32.lib mswsock.lib advapi32.lib /OUT:bin/regular/dll01.dll
> dll01.cpp
>    Creating library bin\regular\dll01.lib and object bin\regular\dll01.exp
> --- Building bin/regular/app00.exe ---
>         cl /nologo -Zi -Od -DDEBUG -DCRTAPI1=_cdecl -DCRTAPI2=_cdecl -nologo -GS -D_AMD64_=1 -DWIN64 -D_WIN64  -DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -W4 -D_WINNT -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DNTDDI_VERSION=0x06000000 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0700 -DWINVER=0x0600  -D_MT -D_DLL -MDd /EHsc /Iinclude /D_DEBUG /Gy app00/src/app00.cpp  /link /NOLOGO /DEBUG /DEBUGTYPE:cv /INCREMENTAL /LIBPATH:bin/regular dll01.lib  /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO -subsystem:console,6.0 kernel32.lib  ws2_32.lib mswsock.lib advapi32.lib /OUT:bin/regular/app00.exe
> app00.cpp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: Build with /OPT:REF
> [prompt]> nmake /nologo /f Makefile.mak OPTREF=NONempty clean all
>         del /f /q "bin/optref"\*
>         del /f /q *.lib *.exp *.pdb *.obj *.idb
> --- Building bin/optref/dll00.dll ---
>         cl /nologo -Zi -Od -DDEBUG -DCRTAPI1=_cdecl -DCRTAPI2=_cdecl -nologo -GS -D_AMD64_=1 -DWIN64 -D_WIN64  -DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -W4 -D_WINNT -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DNTDDI_VERSION=0x06000000 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0700 -DWINVER=0x0600  -D_MT -D_DLL -MDd /EHsc /Iinclude /D_DEBUG /Gy /DDLL00_EXPORTS dll00/src/dll00.cpp  /link /NOLOGO /DEBUG /DEBUGTYPE:cv /INCREMENTAL /OPT:REF /LIBPATH:bin/optref  /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO -entry:_DllMainCRTStartup -dll kernel32.lib  ws2_32.lib mswsock.lib advapi32.lib /OUT:bin/optref/dll00.dll
> dll00.cpp
>    Creating library bin\optref\dll00.lib and object bin\optref\dll00.exp
> --- Building bin/optref/lib00.lib ---
>         cl /nologo -Zi -Od -DDEBUG -DCRTAPI1=_cdecl -DCRTAPI2=_cdecl -nologo -GS -D_AMD64_=1 -DWIN64 -D_WIN64  -DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -W4 -D_WINNT -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DNTDDI_VERSION=0x06000000 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0700 -DWINVER=0x0600  -D_MT -D_DLL -MDd /EHsc /Iinclude /D_DEBUG /Gy /DLIB00_STATIC /c lib00/src/lib00.cpp
> lib00.cpp
>         lib /NOLOGO /DEBUG /DEBUGTYPE:cv /INCREMENTAL /OPT:REF /LIBPATH:bin/optref lib00.obj dll00.lib /OUT:bin/optref/lib00.lib
> LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/DEBUG'; ignored
> LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/DEBUGTYPE:cv'; ignored
> LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/INCREMENTAL'; ignored
> LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/OPT:REF'; ignored
> --- Building bin/optref/dll01.dll ---
>         cl /nologo -Zi -Od -DDEBUG -DCRTAPI1=_cdecl -DCRTAPI2=_cdecl -nologo -GS -D_AMD64_=1 -DWIN64 -D_WIN64  -DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -W4 -D_WINNT -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DNTDDI_VERSION=0x06000000 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0700 -DWINVER=0x0600  -D_MT -D_DLL -MDd /EHsc /Iinclude /D_DEBUG /Gy /DDLL01_EXPORTS /DLIB00_STATIC dll01/src/dll01.cpp  /link /NOLOGO /DEBUG /DEBUGTYPE:cv /INCREMENTAL /OPT:REF /LIBPATH:bin/optref  /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO -entry:_DllMainCRTStartup -dll lib00.lib kernel32.lib  ws2_32.lib mswsock.lib advapi32.lib /OUT:bin/optref/dll01.dll
> dll01.cpp
>    Creating library bin\optref\dll01.lib and object bin\optref\dll01.exp
> --- Building bin/optref/app00.exe ---
>         cl /nologo -Zi -Od -DDEBUG -DCRTAPI1=_cdecl -DCRTAPI2=_cdecl -nologo -GS -D_AMD64_=1 -DWIN64 -D_WIN64  -DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -W4 -D_WINNT -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DNTDDI_VERSION=0x06000000 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0700 -DWINVER=0x0600  -D_MT -D_DLL -MDd /EHsc /Iinclude /D_DEBUG /Gy app00/src/app00.cpp  /link /NOLOGO /DEBUG /DEBUGTYPE:cv /INCREMENTAL /OPT:REF /LIBPATH:bin/optref dll01.lib  /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO -subsystem:console,6.0 kernel32.lib  ws2_32.lib mswsock.lib advapi32.lib /OUT:bin/optref/app00.exe
> app00.cpp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: Run the executables
> [prompt]> bin\regular\app00.exe
> [lib00/src/lib00.cpp] 8 (Lib00Cls00::meth00)
> [dll01/src/dll01.cpp] 10 (Dll01Cls00::meth00)
> [app00/src/app00.cpp] 8 (main)
>
> [prompt]> bin\optref\app00.exe
> [lib00/src/lib00.cpp] 8 (Lib00Cls00::meth00)
> [dll01/src/dll01.cpp] 10 (Dll01Cls00::meth00)
> [app00/src/app00.cpp] 8 (main)
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: Test dll01.dll (for dll00.dll dependency) in the 2 directories
> [prompt]> dumpbin /DEPENDENTS bin\regular\dll01.dll | findstr dll00
>     dll00.dll
>
> [prompt]> dumpbin /DEPENDENTS bin\optref\dll01.dll | findstr dll00
>
> [prompt]>
> ```

So, it **is** possible to eliminate the (unused) dependency via compile / link flags.

There are a number of ways to move forward, each with its benefits and drawbacks. It depends very much on your environment (and workflows you have in place):

- Build system:

  - *VStudio* (that I assume you're using, based on compile and link commands)
  - *NMake*
  - *CMake*
  - Other
- How large your projects are
- Whether the static library (with 3<sup>rd</sup>-party *.dll* dependency is used in other projects)
- Many others

Below there are some that I came up with (there may be others). Choose whichever suits you best:

1. Modify build options:

   - */Gy* (compile) for the static library (at least)
   - */OPT:REF* (link) for the *.dll* linking the static library

   Most obvious (and simplest) one
2. Clean the static library code by removing the 3<sup>rd</sup>-party *.dll* references. If there's code that is not used, it's just a pile of garbage, which makes it very hard to maintain.
   The drawback is that it will require more work
3. Refactor the static library. If for some reason cleaning is not possible (a variant that does use the 3<sup>rd</sup>-party *.dll* is required for some other project), it could use some adjustments:

   1. Split it in 2 separate parts (*.lib*s): one that uses the 3<sup>rd</sup>-party *.dll* and another that doesn't. In your *plugin.dll* only link the latter
   2. Do some conditional building (based on some macro). But that's a bit trickier when setting the options from the *IDE*. [[MS.Learn]: comment pragma](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/comment-c-cpp) could come in handy

   Even more work (compared to previous) will be required

Might also worth reading (including referenced *URL*s):

- [[SO]: Excel VBA, Can't Find DLL Entry Point from a DLL file (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44177222/4788546)
- [[SO]: Visual Studio NMake build fails with: fatal error U1052: file 'win32.mak' not found (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73167842/4788546)
- [[SO]: Discover missing module using command-line ("DLL load failed" error) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74883130/4788546)